# Does anyone know what's up with this question?

Tags: discussion

So this is in the review queue and the entire thing is a mess:

- ['mount: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0 : no such file or directory' error while booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354837/total-boot-failure-xubuntu-12-04-2-desktop-amd64-mount-error-while-loading-s)

Does anyone have any recommendations on fixing this?

Comment: Well it appears answered...

Comment: Answered isn't good enough; the 43980357457 comments and noise all over them make me cry.

Comment: Which killing them all, and then having people start over from scratch be a acceptable solution?

Comment: I left two comments and OP seems pretty unwilling to reinstall, so I moved along... I don't see how the wireless has something to do with it...

Comment: Less talk, more fixing ;)

Comment: User also got a "smack in the hands" for [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/356310/how-to-manually-install-or-replace-lib-files-they-come-as-deb-files). Just shows what kind of *"help"* he is looking for...

Answer (score 13):

The whole thing is trash.  There is a lot of immaturity and noise on the whole thing, both the question and the answer.

Users of Ask Ubuntu need to focus a bit more on the quality of their posts and focus on the facts of the help request, instead it seems that people do not understand what the site is about.

I am cleaning that bloody thing and clearing the comments that are irrelevant to the posts. It's not that complicated to focus on the message and ignore the crap around it; any editor can do that.

Comment: I salute you sir!

Comment: We need a prominent "Zen of AskUbuntu" (like the Zen of Python) somewhere.